# Passing an argument to an endpoint to be used inside the function performed in an event hook

Tags: python, events, hook, endpoint, eve

I have a function that it is performed over a mongodb collection called `tab0001`. My function works greatly:

```
from eve import Eve

def my_func(response):

    resposta = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response['_items'])
    resposta = resposta.drop(columns = ['_id','var0030','var0053','var0052','var0058', 'var0057', 'var0028', 'var0029', 'var0059','_created', '_updated', '_etag', '_links'])
    resposta = resposta.groupby('var0046', as_index=False).sum()

    num_emp_total = sum(resposta['var0055'])
    massa_sal_total = sum(resposta['var0054'])

    mercado_num_emp = sum(((resposta['var0055']/num_emp_total) ** 2 ) * 10000)
    mercado_massa_sal = sum(((resposta['var0054']/massa_sal_total) ** 2 ) * 10000)

    response.clear()
    response['ind0063'] = mercado_massa_sal
    response['ind0062'] = mercado_num_emp

app = Eve()
app.on_fetched_resource_func += my_func
app.run()
```

However, I would like to add an argument "n" to also be an argument of my_func(response, n) but the value of n is given by the client using the url endpoints. Without the parameter n, I access my function through:

`"127.0.0.1:2000/func"`

If I would like a filter on the collection `tab0001` before the execution of the my_func, I would do:

Example: `"127.0.0.1:2000/func?where{"var0059":2016}"` and it filters the data by the year 2016 and perform my_func correctly!

However, I am in a case that I also need to be able to allow the client to choose a value of `n` that it is going to be used inside the function. Different values of n in different filters of the collection, return different results.

So, I have goggled about post request event hooks but I have not figured how to adjust to my problem (also the settings.py file). In my thinking, the url endpoint would be something like:

`"127.0.0.1:2000/func?where{"var0059":2016}&n=5"`

My settings.py is like:

```
MONGO_URI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/portal_db"

tab_schema = {
    "schema": {
        "var0030":{"type": "integer"},
        "var0053":{"type": "integer"},
        "var0052":{"type": "integer"},
        "var0058":{"type": "integer"},
        "var0054":{"type": "integer"},
        "var0055":{"type": "integer"},
        "var0046":{"type": "string"},
        "var0057":{"type": "integer"},
        "var0028":{"type": "string"},
        "var0029":{"type": "integer"},
        "var0059":{"type": "integer"}
    }
}

func = {
    'datasource': {
        'source': 'tab0043'
    },
    "schema": {
        "var0030":{"type": "integer"},
        "var0053":{"type": "integer"},
        "var0052":{"type": "integer"},
        "var0058":{"type": "integer"},
        "var0054":{"type": "integer"},
        "var0055":{"type": "integer"},
        "var0046":{"type": "string"},
        "var0057":{"type": "integer"},
        "var0028":{"type": "string"},
        "var0029":{"type": "integer"},
        "var0059":{"type": "integer"}
    },
    'pagination': False
}

DOMAIN = {
    "tab0043": tab_schema,
    "func": func
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eve is built on Flask. You can access [Flask's request context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/reqcontext/) *via* the request proxy.

```
from flask import request

def my_func(response):
    ...
    # here we want to get the value of n (e.g. ?n=some-value)
    n = request.args.get('n')
```